# Make a div take up the full space not used by margins

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to create a content container in the middle of my site that can be no wider than a certain size (1194px), and will always have at least 242px margins on the left and right sides. If the container is wider than 1194px, the margins will grow. If the container is smaller than 1194px, the margins will stay 242px, shrinking the width of the container. [image: Here's an image to explain better.] Here's what I'm using and isn't working.

```
.mainContainer {
    margin-left:242px;
    margin-right:242px;
    max-width:1194px;
}
```

But the container shrinks to fit the content. If I specify `width:100%;`, the margins will grow when the container is bigger than max, but the container will not shrink. What am I missing?

---

As a sub problem; I'm doing this in order to make my page responsive. Inside `.mainContainer`, there is a series of `.projectContainer`'s, each 384px wide with 7px margin all sides. The width (including margins) of 3 of these adds up to the 1194px of `.mainContainer`. As of thus far, these values have been static. But now that `.mainContainer` is going to be fluid, I want the `.projectContainer` widths to also be fluid—as `.mainContainer` decreases in width, so should the `.projectConatiner`'s.

My math figures that each `.projectContainer`, not including the 7px margin on each side, should be taking up 32.160804% of the `.mainContainer`:

```
384px * 3 = 1152px
1152px / 1194px = 0.96482412
0.96482412 / 3 = 0.32160804
```

Yet giving a value of `width:32.160804%;` to `.projectConatiner` doesn't seem to work. Is it a rounding error? How could I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: JS is a way to go. P.S (Haven't read the question properly/fully but seems like CSS is not a good candidate for so much calculation)

Comment: You need to solve this with @MediaQueries

Comment: yes media queries will sweets your need

Comment: @Mr.Alien The CSS Is not doing the calculating, that was done by hand. I'm simply trying to set the width of an element to a certain percentage using CSS, which should be easily possible

Comment: @Anzeo Pardon the naivety, but MediaQueries? Is that something I should tag the post with?

Comment: Sure, tagging your questions with relevant tags is a great way to get your questions noticed.

Comment: You can use viewport units to calculate width along with media queries. [Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/L9b38o0j/9/embedded/result/). The issue is [its not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem:

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u9en8eb/1/)

you can define the margin auto for the child div(width 1194 div), and min-`width:1194+242+242=1678px` for container,

this will make sure there is minimum margin of 242px on both sides, and when the page width increases the margin will increase(not the child width), and child remains `1194px` only

```
<div class='container'>

    <div class='child'>1194px</div>

</div>
    .container{
        min-width:1678px;
        height:70px;
        background:green;
    }
.child{
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    width:1194px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want the child be static at 1194, I want it to be it's container's width minus the 242(*2) margin from either side. That is, unless the child is 1194px and it's container is wider, in which case the child should remain 1194px and the margins should increase.

Comment: @GtwoK.. see this, you can instead give padding to the parent container to acheive thi http://jsfiddle.net/1u9en8eb/4/

Comment: Great! That fiddle works perfectly. Thanks so much. Would you happen to know what would cause a div to not expand to it's full capable width though? If I have more than the 3 projectContainers in there, it pushes the 4th down to a new line (as it should) and the line break fills out the rest of the width. But if I only have 2 projectContainers in there, it only takes up the width of the 2 projectContainers for some reason. It's not filling it full possible width (up to 1194px).

Comment: @GtwoK if you want to fill two or three `.projectContainer` divs, and dont know exactly how many of them there actually would be, then you should set the width with javascript..  iguess even mediaQuearies wont work in that case

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain myself properly; naturally, a div should fill the available space (horizontally), unless assigned a certain width. It does this in your fiddle as well, as it should—`child` fills `container`, unless it reaches it's max-width of 1194px. But when I test it on my own site, the child does not fill the space available. Here's an image of the padding working properly on the container (`#gallery`) http://i.imgur.com/r5YgM3o.png

And here is the child (`.mainContainer`), the blue representing the space it takes up http://i.imgur.com/BNN41sl.png

Comment: @GtwoK.. do you want your `child` div to grow beyond `1194px` if the parent has spave left? if this is the case you can remove the max-width from child like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1u9en8eb/9/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71156/discussion-between-gtwok-and-naeem-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1194px) {
   code css 
}
```

for responsive style

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's happening here. Could you link to some sort of documentation I could read up on?

Comment: like this 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

Comment: Ah, I see. This won't actually accomplish what I'm looking for in the question I asked, but it will be very useful to me in a bit for something else. Thanks for showing me!

Answer (score 0):

Use this buddy. No need for responsive css cause this is already responsive.

```
.mainContainer {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1194px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: How will this make sure the margins are at least 242px?

Comment: On my case, I did not use too much margins on left or right alignment. Instead use the margin 0 auto to centralized the element. This *margins are at least 242px* will cause you so much trouble on different window screen.

Comment: The OP specifically requested the margins be at least 242px on each side. It may be true this would cause issues on smaller screens, but the you should state this obviously in your answer. Without any context it seems as if you didn't understand the question.